# Using AWS Cognito from Lambda for .NET

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am dipping my toes into unauthenticated/anonymous user access in AWS and was hoping to get the generated token from Cognito via the Lambda.

I have not been able to get it to run in the lambda with the following error.

`This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly`

```
{
  "errorType": "NotImplementedException",
  "errorMessage": "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the AWSSDK.Core NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Util.Internal.PlatformServices.ApplicationSettings.GetValue(String key, ApplicationSettingsMode mode)",
    "at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials.GetCachedIdentityId()",
    "at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials..ctor(String accountId, String identityPoolId, String unAuthRoleArn, String authRoleArn, IAmazonCognitoIdentity cibClient, IAmazonSecurityTokenService stsClient)",
    "at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials..ctor(String accountId, String identityPoolId, String unAuthRoleArn, String authRoleArn, RegionEndpoint region)",
    "at AwsDotnetCsharp.AuthHandler.Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
  ]
}
```

The Lambda is the newer C# dotnet core version rather than javascript. I am referencing AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.SecurityToken in project.json

So is the `CognitoAWSCredentials` not compatible (yet) with dotnet core (.net Standard 1.6) which at the time of writng is version 3.3.1.1 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity/) thought on the nuget site it says it is.

My lambda code is ... (might be not right but I cannot get it to run to move forward)

```
public class AuthHandler
    {
        public APIGatewayProxyResponse Get(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            CognitoAWSCredentials credentials =
                new CognitoAWSCredentials("us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            var identityPoolId = credentials.GetIdentityIdAsync();

            AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(
                credentials, // the anonymous credentials
                Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1 // the Amazon Cognito region
            );

            GetIdRequest idRequest = new GetIdRequest();
            idRequest.AccountId = "############";
            idRequest.IdentityPoolId = identityPoolId.Result;

            var idResp = cognitoClient.GetIdAsync(idRequest);

            var id = idResp.Result.IdentityId;

            var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = $"{{ \"{id}\" }}",
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "application/json" } }
            };

            return response;
        }
    }
```

What is required to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue here is that the AWSSDK.Core module for .net Framework 4.5 and .net Standard do not implement the `Amazon.Util.Internal.PlatformServices.IApplicationSettings` interface. The exception message indicates its only implemented for platform specific versions, like Xamarin, Windows Phone, and Windows Universal. You can see the implementations here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/tree/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/Internal/PlatformServices

Rather than using the `CognitoAWSCredentials` object, you'll need to work around it by calling `AmazonCognitoIdentityClient` directly.

A sample to get the AWS identity using the client is at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-amazon-cognito-in-your-website-for-simple-aws-authentication/

```
// initialize a set of anonymous AWS credentials for our API calls
AnonymousAWSCredentials cred = new AnonymousAWSCredentials ();

// initialize the Cognito identity client and prepare a request object
// to get the identity id
AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(
    cred, // the anonymous credentials
    RegionEndpoint.USEast1 // the Amazon Cognito region
);

GetIdRequest idRequest = new GetIdRequest ();
idRequest.AccountId = "YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID";
idRequest.IdentityPoolId = "YOUR_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID";
// set the Dictionary of logins if you are authenticating users 
// through an identity provider
//idRequest.Logins = new Dictionary {
//  { "graph.facebook.com", "FacebookSessionToken" }
//};

// The identity id is in the IdentityId parameter of the response object
GetIdResponse idResp = cognitoClient.GetId (idRequest);
```